# QML Checking for the cross of elements with different parents

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have many elements of the same type (Point.qml) at different nesting levels.
How can I check that some element (id: checker) cross one of these elements (Point)?

For Example:

```
// Point.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {

   width: 10
   height: 10

   color: "black"

}
```

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Rectangle {
        id: area;
        anchors.fill:  parent


        RowLayout
        {
            anchors.fill:  parent

            Repeater
            {
                model: 5
                Rectangle
                {
                    width: Math.random()*150+50
                    height: Math.random()*150+50
                    color: "blue"

                    Point {
                        x : Math.random()*parent.width
                        y : Math.random()*parent.height
                    }

                }
            }
            Point {
                x : Math.random()*parent.width
                y : Math.random()*parent.height
            }

        }
        Point {
            x : Math.random()*parent.width
            y : Math.random()*parent.height
        }



        Rectangle
        {
            id: checker

            width: 60
            height: 60
            color: "red"
            opacity: 0.5

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent

                onReleased:
                {
                    var point = getCoveredPoint()
                    if (point)
                    {
                        console.log("Point ", point, " is covered")
                    }
                }

                function getCoveredPoint()
                {
                    var point
                    // do something
                    return point
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this example, when the red Rectangle (id: checker) stops at the black Point, a message should be output to the console. Points and "checker" are in the same parent element (id: area)

Comment: you can use [Item.mapToGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method) to recalculate position of items and so check the intersection

Comment: @folibis, Yes, it will work, but how do I figure out what to look for an intersection with? The checking element (red rectangle) only knows that somewhere in the workspace (area) there are these Points. How can it get recursive access to childs of a certain type? Or ALL the elements that are included in the scope of the checking element

Comment: In fact, this means that there is some kind of problem in the architecture of the application. I would put all the elements at the same canvas. If not, you should have a list of all the points .In fact, the solution depends on how your application is really built.